# Can't install linux-headers-3.13.0.35-generic, crashes on VMWare and VirtualBox

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, virtualization, vmware, 14.10

i've installed ubuntu 14.10 and i got some troubles trying to run a virtual machine. I've tried all to run VirtualBox and VMWare, but without success. Both programs ask me for linux-headers-3.13.0.35-generic but i can't install them.

I have installed linux-headers-3.16.0-24-generic, i tried to uninstall it ( i don't know if this is correct), i ve tried to update, i've tried everything that i can find on internet. Also i've tried reinstalling dkms, reinstalling vbox and vmware. I don't know what happens, and i need it to run an os i'm developing. I hope you can help me, i've been trying this for 3 days.

Thanks, Jorge

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to have some trouble with the 3.13 headers, because the kernel installed with 14.10 is 3.16.  You can check which kernel you are running by entering `uname -r`, and your headers should match this version.

Comment: When i run that it tells me i'm running 3.13.0-35-generic. But when i search on usr/src only appears 3.16.0.24